# What is the "TransitionProps" param in Material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm learning how to use Material-ui for ReactJS, I don't understand what is the "TransitionProps" in this example code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Popper from '@material-ui/core/Popper';
import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    border: '1px solid',
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
}));

export default function TransitionsPopper() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(anchorEl ? null : event.currentTarget);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? 'transitions-popper' : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
      <button aria-describedby={id} type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Toggle Popper
      </button>
      
<Popper id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl} transition>
        {({ TransitionProps }) => (
          <Fade {...TransitionProps} timeout={350}>
            <div className={classes.paper}>The content of the Popper.</div>
          </Fade>
        )}
</Popper>

    </div>
  );
}
```

What will be passed into "TransitionProps"?

[Here is the source code on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mu8mc)

Hoping someone will explain some more on this syntax.
Thanks.

Comment: the transition props are a boolean `in` and then an `onEnter` and `onExited`. It's just using destructuring to get those values.

Comment: I have logged TransitionProps on the screen. Hope this helps. [Updated Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-3p71c)

Comment: oh i got it. Thanks. So how can it change true/false when the handleClick fires? I thought this line {({ TransitionProps }) => (...)} just defined a anonymous function and I must have a code calling it somewhere?